# How can python get %SystemRoot% without CMD 'echo %SystemRoot%'?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, system, root

How can Python find the Windows systemroot without referring to CMD command `echo %SystemRoot%`?

Comment: Have you tried `import os; os.path.expandvars("%SystemRoot%")`?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Python os module.

```
# Get environment variables
sr = os.getenv('SystemRoot')
sr = os.environ.get('SystemRoot')
```

https://able.bio/rhett/how-to-set-and-get-environment-variables-in-python--274rgt5

To see what else the os module can do, use:

```
dir(os)
```

To see specifics of an item, use:

```
print(os.getenv.__doc__)
```

Comment: Normally a script would use `os.environ['SystemRoot']`, which will raise a `KeyError` if the environment variable isn't defined. Maybe the error can be handled, and missing "%SystemRoot%" can be handled by calling `GetSystemDirectoryW` with ctypes. OTOH, `os.environ.get` will return `None` if the environment variable isn't defined. If code isn't checking for this sentinel value, it will just get an exception later when the script tries to use the result as a string. I know the linked page explains these return values, but it's too fundamental to omit from an answer.